# jQuery Tooltip using only javaScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am working on a map application and I would like to use a tooltip when mouseOver occurs on a map object.

Can I use the jquery ui tooltip without html and only with javaScript?

For example

```
var name
var myObjectOptions = {
    featureOver: function(name) {
        //here is where I would like to show a jquery tooltip that is at mouse x,y and displays the name variable
    },
    featureOut: function(name) {
        //on mouse out the tooltip would not longer be displayed
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to append the jQuery tooltep to an html element, so I think you can't.

Comment: What do you mean by "without html"? Your browser displays html elements. You can append an element using jQuery and then remove it again, but you need an html element somewhere.

Comment: Using the ui-tooltip I normally set title="some some title" in my div.  Then the tooltip appears on my div. I want a tooltip to appear at my mouse's position with text equal to a javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

In past projects, I found [the jQuery plugin imageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/) to be of great value in creating image maps. It includes a simple method for handling tooltips.

Here is an example of using the tooltip:

```
        // if Asparagus selected, change the tooltip
        if (e.key === 'asparagus') {
            newToolTip = "OK. I know I have come down on the dip before...";
        }
```

[See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/)

[Here are a few more examples](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#usa)

Comment: I already have listeners on my map objects that fire on mouseOver. I would prefer to simply show a tooltip @ x,y on that event